# Simple javascript datepicker

Tags: javascript, html, datepicker

Working on a simple javascript datepicker. Found one good here:    `http://www.monkeyphysics.com/mootools/script/2/datepicker#examples`

So I am trying it to work but as you can see its not working:
    http://jsfiddle.net/R4JZ6/

Comment: Why not using jQuery UI date picker?

Comment: `MooTools DatePicker` it need's the `MooTools` JS library, are you including that?

Comment: I just need a simple javascript datepicker. So weird why that is not working actually.

Comment: Additionally in your fiddle you specified that the code is under onload then you are binding window. onload.. and this is incorrect you should request to place it in body or head.. and it is addEventListener not addEvent

Comment: `addEvent` is a MooTools member

Comment: Aha.. when I opened the fiddle I couldn't see MooTools selected so that made me confused

Comment: Thanks! I found the html5 date pretty good. One question is it possible to make it standard to show todays date and if the user want to change it they will have the possibilty to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just use a simple HTML date input type?

Like this:

```
<input name='date_B' type='date' value='' class='date demo'/>
```

As you can see all I did was change the input type to date rather than text.

Comment: While this is true, support for this input is [terrible](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-datetime). It's probably not viable to use this in a project yet...

Comment: Problem is that it's not working in firefox not tested if it works in IE. The other problem is that it has to show the todays date as default and if the user want to change it they will have the possibility to do so.

Comment: Ok I see. Let me get back to you on this

Comment: Totally true! I read about this in a book back in 2010, and now, 4 years later, it's still not implemented in latest Firefox. So not cool!